# How to recover colon command removed by <C-U>?

Tags: command-line

In terminal, the command of the line of the input prompt can be cleared with `<C-U>`, and is recoverable with `<C-Y>`.

In vim, the colon command can be cleared with `<C-U>`, but it is not recoverable with `<C-Y>`. Is it possible to recover those erased commands?

Comment: I don't think it's possible natively (at least I didn't find anything relevant in the doc). Saving what you typed before using `<c-u>` can be done with [`:h CmdlineChanged`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#CmdlineChanged) and [`:h getcmdline()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getcmdline%28%29) but modifying the command line with a mapping is the non trivial part.

Answer (score 3):

Somewhat workaround if you have recent vim with `<cmd>` support:

```
cnoremap <C-u> <cmd>let g:CCtrlU = strpart(getcmdline(),0,getcmdpos()-1)<CR><C-u>
cnoremap <C-y> <C-r>=get(g:, "CCtrlU", "")<CR><cmd>let g:CCtrlU = ''<CR>
```

With `<cmd>` it is possible to run arbitrary vimscript without changing modes,
so here with

- `<C-u>` part of the cmdline is saved from beginning to the cursor pos, then original `<C-u>` deletes what it should.
- `<C-y>` uses expression register `=` to output saved cmdline (`g:CCtrlU` is in safe form, checking existence with default value `""`) and then cleans up variable that holds saved cmdline.

PS, alternatively if you don't mind `<C-u>` to cut text into unnamed register, it could be simplified to:

```
cnoremap <C-u> <cmd>let @" = strpart(getcmdline(),0,getcmdpos()-1)<CR><C-u>
cnoremap <C-y> <C-r>"
```

PPS, and if you don't have `<cmd>` in your vim you could try this with `<expr>` and additional func:

```
func! CCtrlU() abort
    let @" = strpart(getcmdline(),0,getcmdpos()-1)
    return "\<C-u>"
endfunc
cnoremap <expr> <C-u> CCtrlU()
cnoremap <C-y> <C-r>"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea which is probably not ideal but could be in the right direction. The idea is to make use of the event [`:h CmdlineChanged`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#CmdlineChanged) which is triggered each time a character is changed in the command line.

On this event we get the content of the command line with [`:h getcmdline()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getcmdline%28%29) and we use [`:h :execute`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3Aexecute) to remap `<C-y>` to this string we got.

```
augroup CmdSave
    autocmd!
    autocmd CmdlineChanged * execute "cnoremap <C-y> " . getcmdline()
augroup END
```

As the autocommand is triggered also by `<C-u>` you can then press `<C-y>` to get the content back. The drawback is that if you press `<C-y>` at any moment other than right after `<C-u>` that will mess up your command line. Also it's very probable that some special characters will break the mapping (e.g. this substitution `s/./^v/g` with `<CR>` entered with <kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd> will end up in two commands)

**EDIT** Yeah so there are some side effects. I won't investigate the reason but my autocommand breaks the `:Git commit` feature of vim-figutive, so I also probably breaks other things. Once could try to wrap everything in a `try...catch` block but at this point it become really too hacky.

Answer (score 1):

First, `<c-u>` doesn't actually clear the entire cmdline, only the part before the cursor.  There is a note in `:help c_CTRL-U` about this. I'll assume from the question you want to clear the entire cmdline.

On the cmdline, another way to clear the entry is `<c-c>`.  Unlike `<c-u>` this adds the current text to the history.  I suggest the following map:

```
cnoremap <c-u> <c-c>:
```

Then, to recover the line after clearing simply press up.